# Efficient algorithm for merging objects in ArrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, java-8

I have an ArrayList of custom objects (DTO) , the structure of DTO:

```
private String id;
private String text;
private String query;
private String locatorId;
private Collection<String> categories;
private Collection<String> triggers;
```

I have two task:

- Remove duplicates in Array (it seems OK, I should use HashSet)
- Find objects in ArrayList with the same id field and merge them into one object (I should merge fields categories and triggers) and create final List with merged objects.

What is the most efficient approach for such task? Also I'm interesting to use **Lambda** expression in my algorithm.

Comment: How do you merge text, query and category?

Comment: This fields won't be merged (they will be the same, only difference in fields categories and triggers).

Answer (score 4):

It's quite easy to merge objects by specified key using the stream API. First, define a `merge` method in your `Entity` class like this:

```
public Entity merge(Entity other) {
    this.categories.addAll(other.categories);
    this.triggers.addAll(other.triggers);
    return this;
}
```

Then you can build a custom grouping collector:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public static Collection<Entity> mergeAll(Collection<Entity> input) {
    return input.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Entity::getId,
                    collectingAndThen(reducing(Entity::merge), Optional::get)))
                .values();
}
```

Here we group `Entity` elements by the result of `getId` method and downstream collector just calls `Entity.merge()` when the same `id` is encountered (we need to unfold on `Optional` additionally). No special `hashCode()` or `equals()` implementation is necessary for `Entity` in this solution.

Note that this solution modifies the existing unmerged `Entity` objects. If it's undesirable, create a new `Entity` in the `merge()` method and return it instead  (as in @Marco13 answer).

Comment: or `toMap(Entity::getId, e->e, Entity::merge)` as an alternative to `groupingBy` - `reducing`

Comment: @Misha, thanks. Probably I have too much `groupingBy` way of thinking and always forget about `toMap` alternative.

Comment: Note also that unless `categories` and `triggers` are `Set`s, the merge method will possibly generate duplicate entries into said `Collections`, which may not be what the OP means by "merging".

Comment: @MickMnemonic, OP already agreed in the question that using `HashSet` is fine for him.

Comment: `groupingBy` wouldn't be so bad if unwrapping the `Optional` weren't so awkward.  I wish we could do `reducing(Entity::merge).andThen(Optional::get)` via a default method on `Collector` so it would read more naturally left to right instead of the `collectingAndThen` static.

Comment: @TagirValeev, I don't see this stated anywhere in the question, unless you mean "Remove duplicates in Array (it seems OK, I should use HashSet)" (which to me is quite ambiguous and seems to relate to the "Array" of DTOs)?

Answer (score 2):

Create `Map<Integer, DTO>` and put your id as key and object as DTO. And before putting into map just check if it already contain that key and if it does contain that key then take out the DTO object for that key and merge categories and triggers with the old object.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution, as suggested in the [answer by Naman Gala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31784021/3182664), is to use a `Map` from the IDs to the entities, and manually merge the entities when they have the same ID.

This is implemented here in the `mergeById` method, with some dummy/example input where

- two entities have to be merged (due to the same ID)
- two entities are equal (they will also be "merged", yielding the same result as one of the inputs)

.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;


public class MergeById
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
        entities.add(new Entity("0", "A", "X", "-1", 
            Arrays.asList("C0", "C1"), Arrays.asList("T0", "T1")));
        entities.add(new Entity("0", "A", "X", "-1", 
            Arrays.asList("C2", "C3"), Arrays.asList("T2")));
        entities.add(new Entity("1", "B", "Y", "-2", 
            Arrays.asList("C0"), Arrays.asList("T0", "T1")));
        entities.add(new Entity("1", "B", "Y", "-2", 
            Arrays.asList("C0"), Arrays.asList("T0", "T1")));
        entities.add(new Entity("2", "C", "Z", "-3", 
            Arrays.asList("C0", "C1"), Arrays.asList("T1")));

        System.out.println("Before merge:");
        for (Entity entity : entities)
        {
            System.out.println(entity);
        }

        List<Entity> merged = mergeById(entities);

        System.out.println("After  merge:");
        for (Entity entity : merged)
        {
            System.out.println(entity);
        }
    }

    private static List<Entity> mergeById(Iterable<? extends Entity> entities)
    {
        Map<String, Entity> merged = new HashMap<String, Entity>();
        for (Entity entity : entities)
        {
            String id = entity.getId();
            Entity present = merged.get(id);
            if (present == null)
            {
                merged.put(id, entity);
            }
            else
            {
                merged.put(id, Entity.merge(present, entity));
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<Entity>(merged.values());
    }

}


class Entity
{
    private String id;
    private String text;
    private String query;
    private String locatorId;
    private Collection<String> categories;
    private Collection<String> triggers;

    Entity()
    {
        categories = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        triggers = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    }

    Entity(String id, String text, String query, String locatorId,
        Collection<String> categories, Collection<String> triggers)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
        this.query = query;
        this.locatorId = locatorId;
        this.categories = categories;
        this.triggers = triggers;
    }

    String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    static Entity merge(Entity e0, Entity e1)
    {
        if (!Objects.equals(e0.id, e1.id))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Different id");
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(e0.text, e1.text))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Different text");
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(e0.query, e1.query))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Different query");
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(e0.locatorId, e1.locatorId))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Different id");
        }
        Entity e = new Entity(e0.id, e0.text, e0.query, e0.locatorId, 
            new LinkedHashSet<String>(), new LinkedHashSet<String>());
        e.categories.addAll(e0.categories);
        e.categories.addAll(e1.categories);
        e.triggers.addAll(e0.triggers);
        e.triggers.addAll(e1.triggers);
        return e;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Entity [id=" + id + ", text=" + text + ", query=" + query +
            ", locatorId=" + locatorId + ", categories=" + categories +
            ", triggers=" + triggers + "]";
    }

}
```

The output is

```
Before merge:
Entity [id=0, text=A, query=X, locatorId=-1, categories=[C0, C1], triggers=[T0, T1]]
Entity [id=0, text=A, query=X, locatorId=-1, categories=[C2, C3], triggers=[T2]]
Entity [id=1, text=B, query=Y, locatorId=-2, categories=[C0], triggers=[T0, T1]]
Entity [id=1, text=B, query=Y, locatorId=-2, categories=[C0], triggers=[T0, T1]]
Entity [id=2, text=C, query=Z, locatorId=-3, categories=[C0, C1], triggers=[T1]]
After  merge:
Entity [id=0, text=A, query=X, locatorId=-1, categories=[C0, C1, C2, C3], triggers=[T0, T1, T2]]
Entity [id=1, text=B, query=Y, locatorId=-2, categories=[C0], triggers=[T0, T1]]
Entity [id=2, text=C, query=Z, locatorId=-3, categories=[C0, C1], triggers=[T1]]
```

Regarding the request to do this with lambdas: It's probably possible to write some tricky `entities.stream().collect(...)` application. But since this was not the main goal of the question, I'll leave this part of the answer to someone else (but won't omit this small hint: Just because you can does not mean that you have to. Sometimes, a loop is just fine).

Also note that this could easily be generalized, probably lending some vocabulary from databases. But I think that the main point of the question should be answered.

Comment: Thanks @Marco13, I'll take this approach as more efficient for me ( later add some Lambda stuff by myself)

Answer (score 1):

Implement `equals` and `hashCode` based on the `id` field in the DTO and store the DTOs in a `Set`. This should fix both of your problems; given the way equality of your DTOs is now defined, no duplicates with the same `id` can exist in the `Set`.

EDIT:

As your requirement is to merge the categories and triggers of an existing DTO based on values from a new one, then a better suited data structure for storing `DTO`s would be `Map<DTO, DTO>` (because it's cumbersome to retrieve elements back from a `Set` once you've put them in). Also, I think the categories and triggers in your `DTO` should be defined as `Set`s, disallowing duplicates; this will make the merge operation much simpler:

```
private Set<String> categories;
private Set<String> triggers;
```

Assuming the `DTO` provides accessors (`getCategories` / `getTriggers`) for the above fields (and that the fields are never `null`), merging can now be implemented in the following way:

```
public static void mergeOrPut(Map<DTO,DTO> dtos, DTO dto) {
    if (dtos.containsKey(dto)) {
        DTO existing = dtos.get(dto);
        existing.getCategories().addAll(dto.getCategories());
        existing.getTriggers().addAll(dto.getTriggers());
    } else {
        dtos.put(dto, dto);
    }
}
```

The above code can also be easily modified to work with a `Map<Integer, DTO>`, in which case you don't need to override `equals` and `hashCode` in the `DTO` class.

Comment: This won't *merge* the entities with the same IDs. It will just omit one of those whose ID would otherwise be duplicated. Apart from that, I doubt that a sensible implementation of `hashCode` and `equals` is possible when it is solely based on the ID.

Comment: Aggree with @Marco13 , I need not only remove duplicates,but merge objects with the same id .

Comment: @Marco13, an `equals` implementation based on an id alone makes very much sense e.g. when the DTO models an entity that corresponds to a row in a database table.

Comment: @Evgeniy, if you need to merge the entities, then you need to tell us _how_ it should happen.

Comment: @MickMnemonic One could argue about that, but intuitively, when two objects with the same "ID" have different properties, then this "ID" is not an "ID" but just an arbitrary value. (But I'm aware that this intuition may be wrong when referring to the roles of IDs in databases and this "primary key" stuff etc., which I'm not familiar with...)

Comment: @Marco13, when a data transfer object has an identifier property which uniquely identifies the object, I think the only sane way to define equality is through that property alone. I don't know what you mean by the identifier "becoming an arbitrary value".

Comment: @MickMnemonic What I want to say is that it might cause problems when two objects with `(id=0, triggers={A,B})` and `(id=0, triggers={X,Y})` exist in the system at the same time (which is the "right" one?), and that I'd be hesitant to consider them as `equal` (as they *are* not equal: They have different triggers!).

Comment: @EvgeniyKruglov, I have updated my answer so that it now addresses merging the categories and triggers of `DTO`s.

Comment: @Marco13 , sorry , I had to clarify this moment - this id is not an id in database, it's just one another identifier.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist to use lambda expression, you can do the following:

```
Set<X> x = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> 
        ((X)o1).getId().equals(((X)o2).getId()) ? 0 : 1);

List<X> list = new ArrayList<>(set.addAll(x));
```

This will create a set with unique objects according to their ids. Next, for each object in `list`, find the corresponding one from the original list and merge the internal collections.